# Data Factory Dataflow One Partition from Sink Fails to bring data

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a dataflow inside data factory with a sink that is ADLS gen 2. Basically, I'm trying to move some parquet files from one zone to another. The problem comes when regarding the option chosed in the 'Optimize' tab, I'm missing some data at the end of the flow. Did somebody else encountered this?

Comment: Can you give us more details about you problem? what happened and how you set the data flow?

Comment: Hi @LeonYue. Basically, I read from the 'raw' layer from the data lake some parquet files, I do some minimal data transformation inside the dataflow and when the data arrives at Sink - which is again the same ADLS storage, the 'transformed' layer, some data is lost. I've configured in the Optimise tab to keep Current Partitioning and my file format is someting like this: 'timestamp + _ + part[n].parquet'. One of this resulting file is empty for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Partitions in parquet have nothing to do partitions in dataflow. The partitions are formed by splitting files. If you want the same number of files you should use the "Column to store file name" feature on both source and sink and create as many files as source.